# Where shall I ask geohash related questions?

Tags: discussion

Questions related to Geohashing have been asked on SO with `geohashing` tag. Also there is [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) forum under stack exchange dedicated to geographical information related queries. Is it fine to ask Geohashing related question on both forums (so that maximum experts can get visibility)?

Comment: You are asking if you are allowed to ask the same question twice?

Comment: Not exactly. Just not sure difference betweek "gis.stackexchange.com" and "stackoverflow.com with tag geohashing"

Comment: The [gis.se] Stack Exchange is a Q&A site that welcomes focussed questions on Geohashing. It is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account the comment: "Just not sure difference between "gis.stackexchange.com" and "stackoverflow.com with tag geohashing"

That's fair enough - Stackoverflow has very specific rules about what kind of questions you can ask there, probably the gis site has too.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

It really is as simple as "if it follows the rules, you can ask it". Now, lets assume the rare case exists where it seems like you can ask the question on both sites: I would attack that specific choice from your own perspective: on which site will you have the highest chance of getting a relevant answer? Post it there.

I would click around questions asked in gis.stackexchange.com to get a feeling for the kind of person asking and answering questions there. What binds them together? Is their background more technical in nature or more theoretical? That should give you a good idea which question to ask where.